# is there anyway to test my extension methods in the playground

Tags: swift

I was trying out the sample from the apple developer blog, but i notice that the playground does not seem to see the extension.  Is this possible yet?

```
func valuesForKeys2(keys: [Key]) -> [Value?] {
    //this iterates throw each key and executes a function
    //on the class for each value
    return keys.map { self[$0]}
}
```

Comment: which sample you are referring to?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12

Comment: Think i found the answer to my own question here.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045245/how-to-import-own-classes-from-your-own-project-into-a-playground