# iOS Swift Today Extension: import class from container app?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I have an app with a Today widget.  I would like to use a model class from the container app in the `TodayViewController.swift`.

Is such a thing possible?

I copied the file into the Today Extension folder and tried to import it.  No dice.

I can't find an answer in the documentation or online.

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to include the file in the target membership. Select the file and then, in the right hand pane, tick the correct target.

[image]

Comment: No worries, just make sure you continue to add all assets that you retire to both targets. Some APIs aren't available to a Today extension so test regularly.