# Importing classes from playground page into another page

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

Note: This is a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045245/how-to-import-own-classes-from-your-own-project-into-a-playground) than importing generic swift files (which can be done using the Sources folder).

I have a playground with 2 pages and I would like to use a protocol defined in the first page in the second page. I'll use an example of JSON conversion.

JSON.xcplaygroundpage

```
import Foundation

protocol JSONConvertible {
    func jsonValue() -> String
}
```

JSONArray.xcplaygroundpage

```
import Foundation

//Undeclared type JSONConvertible
extension Array : JSONConvertible {

}
```

I have tried the following imports:

```
import MyPlayground
import MyPlayground.JSON
import JSON
import JSON.Contents (in finder the file name is actually Contents.swift)
```

I have also tried adding JSON.xcplaygroundpage into the Source folder of `JSONArray` as well as the Resources folder.

Note: I realize that I could put the protocol definition in a separate `JSON.swift` and include that in my project Sources folder. That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @epologee I did not, sorry.

Comment: So strange, right? Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Even in Xcode 8, you cannot import one playground page into another. However, you can now put code common across multiple pages into a source file. I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 8):

This is working in Xcode 8.3.3.

For code common to multiple pages, put it in separate files under top-level *Sources* group. Be sure to have proper Swift access control keywords in the right places.

Note from http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.2/#/devfa5bea3af:

*...the auxiliary Swift source file must export it using the **public** keyword. This includes classes, methods, functions, variables, and protocols.*

[image: playground source file]
**Common.swift:**

```
public class DoIExist { public init(){ print("Woot!")} }
```

Then you can reference it in all of the other pages. Like this:

[image: playground page]
**Page2:**

```
//: [Previous](@previous)

let d = DoIExist()

//: [Next](@next)
```

You can see that it works because of the console output ("Woot!") and the view results gutter.

---

To achieve this, I followed the directions at the [Apple Xcode documentation about Playgrounds](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.2/#/devfa5bea3af). When Apple inevitably moves those docs and does not provide a forwarding link, read on for how I found it.

I searched for the clues found in the link in **cocoapriest**'s answer: ["ios recipes Playground Help Add Auxilliary Code to a Playground"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ios%20recipes%20Playground%20Help%20Add%20Auxilliary%20Code%20to%20a%20Playground&t=osx&ia=qa). This leads to a document Apple is currently calling "Xcode Help" in a chapter titled "Use playgrounds" in a section titled "Add auxiliary code to a playground".

Comment: My original intention was to create pages where you walked through creating a protocol and then used it later. However, this mostly answers the question because I could add my own version to subsequent page's Sources folder.

Answer (score -1):

Just got this to work with this instruction by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/AddAuxilliaryCodetoaPlayground.html

Make sure to declare your classes are public. Also, I had to re-start the Xcode to take the effect.

Comment: To clarify, you were able to declare a file in one page and import into another page without duplicating the file? I wasn't able to accomplish that with the link you provided

Comment: are you sure you exactly followed all steps? And: there was no "import" in that sense: it was imported automatically for me.

Comment: The link is broken. Please fix it and ideally put a description of the steps in the answer so that if Apple moves it again, it doesn't matter so much. The answer as currently written is completely useless.

Comment: Honestly, if you had not posted that link I would have never tracked down where Apple moved the docs. Thank you.