# Xcode 7.3 and Interactive Playgrounds without creating a Framework

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, interactive, swift-playground

Is there any way to use playgrounds inside an existing project to design and test View Controllers or other project views with Interactive Playgrounds **without creating a Framework**?

I tried to `import ViewController` and similar into playground inside my project but nothing works. I can't access to project files from playgrounds.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import own classes from your own project into a Playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045245/how-to-import-own-classes-from-your-own-project-into-a-playground)

Comment: I need to use classes without using a framework

Comment: If it's not to many you can just write classes in Playground: ``class Temp{}``