# How to use swift playground with custom classes like `rails console` of Ruby on Rails

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to debug quicker and make advantage of playground. I'm currently creating an iOS app and want to use playground as REPL for my project. In playground, I'd like to import custom classes in the project and also 3rd party framework such as Alamofire. Just creating playground in project by `File > New > File…` doesn't make sense. Any good tutorial or anyone who give me an advice?

Comment: google for classes in PlayGround.

Comment: the main idea is: create an target and compile your classes as library (include the needed classes it to a compile target). import this classes into playground. you need to make a workspace around your project to get this done.

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045245/how-to-import-own-classes-from-your-own-project-into-a-playground

Comment: howto: https://medium.com/@LogMaestro/adding-playgrounds-to-your-xcode-project-79d5ea0c7087#.kvzj3qi1y

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import own classes from your own project into a Playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045245/how-to-import-own-classes-from-your-own-project-into-a-playground)