# I can't import AudioKit or AudioKitPlaygrounds in swift Playground file

Tags: swift, swift-playground, audiokit

AudioKit beginner and I really need some help here!

I want to track the frequency and amplitude of a selected audio file in swift language **using playground** on my Mac.

I searched that AudioKit is particularly easy in tracking the frequency and the amplitude, but after downloading AudioKit framework on the official website https://audiokit.io/downloads/ I do not know how to add the framework into my playground file so I could import AudioKit in my code.

Or is there another way to track the frequency and amplitude of an existing "mp3" file **in the Xcode Playground**?

I download the AudioKit Playgrounds file on the website. Xcode still displays "no such module" in pre-compiled playground created by AudioKit team.[image]

Appreciate every answer!

Comment: See [How do I import 3rd party frameworks into Xcode Playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046160/how-to-i-import-3rd-party-frameworks-into-xcode-playground) or [How to import own classes from your own project into a playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045245/how-to-import-own-classes-from-your-own-project-into-a-playground)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioKit comes with playgrounds that already set up to work with the framework. It should be as easy as hitting build (cmd-b) and then starting the playground.  Either add a new page to AudioKit's playgrounds or edit an existing one to start experimenting with your own code. Believe me this is easier than trying to start from scratch.

Comment: I downloaded AudioKit Playgrounds from AudioKit website but my Xcode still cannot recognize the framework. See the screenshot above 

Comment: I have the same problem in 2020. Downloaded the audiokit frameworks.