# Objective-C class properties not viewable on Swift playground

Tags: swift, objective-c, interop, swift-playground, bridging-header

Question about Objective-C and Swift interoperability.
I have some Objective-C headers and implementation files which I am using in a Swift playground for a bridging project. However the Playground does not show any of my Objective-C class properties or methods of the instances of the class in the preview. I can however see properties of instances of URL, CIImage, and NSImage just fine. What step/s am I missing?

```swift
let image = CIImage(contentsOf: myUrl!) // With a url location to the image file on my disk.
```

The Swift Playground shows w, h beside this line.

However for my Objective-C properties of my

```objc
@interface SampleRect : NSObject

/** NSRect contains region of output pixels to render **/

@property CGRect dimensions;

-(id) init;  
@end
```

The properties after setting the preview shows no information on the SampleRect instance.

What keyword or steps am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import own classes from your own project into a Playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045245/how-to-import-own-classes-from-your-own-project-into-a-playground)

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [`CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customplaygrounddisplayconvertible). Playgrounds only supports specialised displays for a limited number of types. That includes `CIImage`, `URL` etc. For other types, only a "structured description" is displayed, which is probably what you are seeing.

Luckily, your `SampleRect` is just a wrapper around a `CGRect`, so you can easily conform to `CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible` and use the wrapped `CGRect` as the playground display.

```
extension SampleRect: CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible {
    var playgroundDescription: Any {
        dimensions
    }
}
```