# How can I test Swift files in Xcode using XCTest without having to build the entire app?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, swift, testing, xctest

What I'm trying to do is test a Swift file frequently after making tiny changes to the file. The file may contain one or more structs and classes.

I don't care about a concept of an "app" because this is purely an academic exercise to practice some new concepts I've learned. I just want to test the file and don't care about the app and anything related to the app.

You may be asking why? Speed. I want it to be really fast to test, right now it takes a few seconds for the most trivial example. I see it does a lot of work to build the targets:

[image]

Comment: You could always try and use a playground. Not sure if that is what you are looking to do though. However, I don't think there is a way to build with only a couple files but I could be wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You should try a Swift Playground.

Here is the description at [developer.apple.com/swift](http://developer.apple.com/swift):

> **Interactive Playgrounds**
>
> Playgrounds make writing Swift code incredibly simple and fun. Type a line of code and the result appears immediately. If your code runs over time, for instance through a loop, you can watch its progress in the timeline assistant. The timeline displays variables in a graph, draws each step when composing a view, and can play an animated SpriteKit scene. When you’ve perfected your code in the playground, simply move that code into your project. Some uses for playgrounds include:
>
> - Design a new algorithm, watching its results every step of the way
> - Create new tests, verifying they work before promoting into your test suite
> - Experiment with new APIs to hone your Swift coding skills

Comment: Why does he need a playground? Why does the app get built when running test cases that don't call it? I want to test code without added stuff like playground. I don't want behind the scenes things, like calls to the application or simulator, going on when I click 'run' or 'test' I simply want to run what the test file says to run.

Comment: Also, since I need to use a playground for now, how in the world do I get it to have access to sister file classes for testing?

Comment: Wow, apparently not. Your answer really isn't solving my problem, even though I have the some question as the asker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029090/can-swift-playgrounds-see-other-source-files-in-the-same-project