# Sources referencing each other in XCode Playgrounds

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I have code in my `Sources/` directory in my Xcode Playground. I can reference them fine in my playground, but how do I allow them to reference each other? For example, suppose I have `A.swift` and `B.swift` files in the `Sources/` directory. I would like to have `A.swift` access something from `B.swift`, but then I get an error saying that things from `B.swift` are undefined in `A.swift`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for the grammar edits, I re-edited things halfway through and didn't re-read everything. Derp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `public` attribute to the classes, methods, and properties that you want to access in other playgrounds. This should solve your problem:

> You have to add public access attribute to your classes, methods and properties in source folder to make them accessible from main playground file as they treated as separate module by compiler

### Update:

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029090/can-swift-playgrounds-see-other-source-files-in-the-same-project), which although is not on this topic specifically I believe answers the question, here is what the accepted answer says:

> They cannot. Playgrounds are self-contained. This will hopefully change in the future.
>
> Edit: As of Xcode 6.3, Playgrounds can now contain supporting code. They still cannot see other code in the same project, but code can be added to the support folder of a Playground that can be used from within the playground. See [the Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=26) for more info.

So, as I said before, thing is the *sources* folder can be accessed, but not thing in other playgrounds.

Comment: This is correct. By default your properties and methods are `internal`

Comment: All of my classes/methods/properties have the `public` attribute and are accessible in the playground and work fine, but different swift files in my `Sources/` directory don't know about each other and can't share classes.

Comment: Dammit, I should have been able to find that. Thank you for your work.