# Accessibility of public code files within source folder in Xcode Playground

Tags: xcode, swift5, swift-playground

I have a playground running in XCode 12.3. When I create public classes with public methods in the `Sources` folder I am able to access these classes in the playground but not within other files in the `Sources` folder.

Example:
`A.swift`(everything public) and `B.swift`(everything public) in the Sources folder. I am able instantiate objects within the playground. But when I try to create a property of type `B` in `A.Swift` the following error occurs:

"Cannot find 'B' in scope". So within the Source folder they don't know of each other even though they are public.

I know there is a other thread with the same question, but there is no clear solution.
([Sources referencing each other in XCode Playgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880727/sources-referencing-each-other-in-xcode-playgrounds))

How can I solve this?

Comment: are you importing them (just like you need to import Foundation or Cocoa)?

Comment: No, how is this possible. But for testing I downloaded a test project which was working for others - there was no import of any files. I wonder if there is a Xcode setting or something like that. Anyways - thanks for your answer.